# Defining metrics in an arbitrary set and consistency across metrics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a set, then a metric is a function $d:\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ that has to satisfy three properties:

1. $d(x,y)=0\Leftrightarrow x=y$
2. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
3. $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(x,z)$

Suppose we have two different metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$, clearly in general we have $d_1(x,y)\neq d_2(x,y)$ (one example of that is the $L_2$ (Euclidian distance) and $L_1$ distance (Manhattan distance) in $\mathbb{R}^2$). Can we say that if $d_1(x,y)\leq d_1(x,z)$, then $d_2(x,y)\leq d_2(x,z)$?

My general question is, what properties will there be between two different metrics defined on the same set? Is there anything to say between $d_1$ and $d_2$?

Comment: I don't think there is anything useful to say. The set $\Bbb{R}$ of points on the real line  can be put into 1-1 correspondence with the set $\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R}$ of points in the plane. This gives you two metrics on $\Bbb{R}$ with no useful properties in common.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on the example you presented?

Comment: If you have a 1-1 correspondence $i : \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R} $, you get two different metrics on $\Bbb{R}$, namely the usual one and one defined by $d_*(x, y) = d(i(x), i(y))$ (where the $d$ on the right-hand side is the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}$. I don't think there is anything useful to say about the relationship between metrics because the given $i$ has no useful geometrical properties.

Comment: So, if one wants to define a metric for any set, one has to determine desirable properties and design a metric that exhibits those properties? And for any set there are many metrics that don't have geometrical properties that are useful?

Comment: That's right or to put it another way, if ww have a set like $\Bbb{R}$ with a given structure (say the structure of an ordered field) then there are many metrics that don't have any useful relationship with that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the only relation between the two metrics is the set they are defined on the same set there's nothing preventing us from picking two completely different metrics (e.g. the Discrete metric and the Euclidian metric).